# Meshes are squished in Unity

Tags: export, unity, .fbx

Not sure if this is a unity or a blender issue.

This is how my mesh looks in blender:
[image: Meshes in Blender]
This is how it looks in unity:
[image]

I exported as an .fbx with default settings, but wihout animations, armature and I applied transforms. My first thoughts was some rigibody that was on this mesh (I downloaded this) but it doesn't seem like it. Some other chess pieces that were on this same file import normally. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know anything about Unity but maybe you need to apply the scale in Blender? (Ctrl A)

Comment: I would say the same, but OP already mentioned applied transforms and also object icon in unity is fine ... Hmm

Comment: Maybe it's a unity issue after all. I had problem in the past with importing meshes and it was always blender fault (actually me using blender wrongly fault haha), so that's I decided to come here first. Thank you for the comments, though!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the origin on the bottom of the object and aligning it to world origin before exporting solved the issue.